# Issue with SQL Server Failover

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have scenario here, I have two Sql Server 'A', 'B'
Both of them are in different resources group
There is Failover group between them, I have deployed this Failover group using ARM template

While deployment, 'A' sql server primary and 'B' is secondary.

Someone performed the Failover on sql server, now 'B' is Primary and 'A' is Secondary.

If I were to deploy the same failover template one more time, It doesn't allow me, As in template 'A' sql server is marked as primary. But on portal it is secondary server.

Can someone let me know how to handle such situation.

Comment: Hi @AstroBoy, is my answer helpful for you?

Comment: @LeonYue : It would get solved, but it include the manual intervention to perform the failover and then deploy the ARM template. I don't want any manual intervention while deployment takes place

Answer (score 0):

You could also performed the `Failover` to switch the secondary server A to primary again:
[image]